# Is the HTTP request URL not part of the HTTP request header?

Tags: php, http

Here's an excerpt from a Wikipedia article:

> In contrast to the GET request method where only a URL and headers are
>   sent to the server, POST requests also include a message body.

Based on that, it looks like the URL is sent separately from the header, but if that's so, why do we use the `header()` method in PHP to set a URL to redirect to?

```
header("Location: http://google.com");
```

Comment: You are confusing HTTP request and HTTP response. PHP header function adds a new header to RESPONSE headers, GET and POST are REQUEST methods.

Comment: In my answer you have an example of a REQUEST and a RESPONSE and you are explained what headers are like.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you want to browse an URL from your browser you type an URL. The browser puts the url inside an HTTP REQUEST like this:

```
GET /path/to/resource.php?var=data1&othervar=data2 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
"empty line"
```

Then a webserver gives you an answer like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Sep 2011 14:37:36 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 149
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
"empty line"
"149 bytes of Response data"
```

Every line like this "Header-Name: header_value\r\n" is an header.
PHP header function adds an header to the response before sending it to user's browser.
In your example the header is:

```
Location: http://google.com
```

And it's added just after the last header before the "empty line" (which is a line which contains only a \r\n).

POST requests are different from GET requests because you have a request body after the "empty line"):

```
POST /path/to/resource.php HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: "number of bytes in the body"
"empty line"
variable=data&othervar=data2
```

In conclusion an HTTP request is made like this:

1. Request/response row (POST or GET followed by url and http version for request, Http version followed by response code and response string for the response) ended with \r\n
2. Request/response headers (header-name: header_value\r\n)
3. empty row (\r\n)
4. Response/request body

PS. Rows are ALWAYS closed by "\r\n" bytes ("empty lines" are made of just those two bytes).

Comment: Is the first quotation `GET /path...` part of the request header?

Comment: Not really, "GET ... HTTP/1.1" and "POST ... HTTP/1.1" are the REQUEST ROW, which are followed by request headers.

Comment: Is it then correct to say that the `Location: ...` header is like an instruction for a new HTTP request?

Comment: Yes, "Location: redirect_url" is an header which tells your browser to make a NEW REQUEST to that url.

Answer (score 2):

`header()` **adds** a header to the file.

So if you want to set the Content-Type:

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

And so on...

`Location` is just another header you can set and/or change with the php `header()` function

From the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a REDIRECT (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.

Comment: Here's another excerpt (this time from the PHP docs): `header() is used to send a raw HTTP header.`

Comment: @Emanuil ... all header are `sent`... that is the idea of a header... read the update to my answer

Comment: You seem to be right. It should be "adds" instead of "sends".

Answer (score 0):

There are response headers and request headers

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

You set the location header in PHP as a response to a request. The browser looks at the response and acts accordingly.

So you go to the original page and the location header tells the browser to go somewhere else.